# NESTjs interceptor logging time performance

Tags: javascript, logging, nestjs, typeorm, interceptor

I want to implement logging performance time for controller and methodes in service, this is my controller

```
  @ApiBody({ type: CatRequestDto })
  @ApiOkResponse({ type: CatResponseDto })
  @ApiOkResponse()
  @Post('Cat')
  public authWithEmail(@Body() body: CatRequestDto): Promise<CatResponseDto> {
    return this.CatService.CatMail(body);
  }
```

and I got time of performance like

Function CatEmail finished in 32.37212496995926ms
Request POST /animal/Cat processed in 32.368833005428314ms

But I want also to get time of performance for all functions that are envoked after  this.CatService.CatMail is called in controller.

for example this is service that is envoked after controller is hit

```
    public async CatMail(payload: CatRequestDto): Promise<CatResponseDto> {
    const animal = await this.CatService.findOneBy({ Cat: payload.Cat });

    if (!user) {
      return this.CatType(payload);
    }
   }
```

I want to logg also time of performance of methode this.CatType like
Function CatType finished in 2ms

Can this be done with nestjs Interceptor?

```
  @Injectable()
  export class PerformanceLoggerInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  public intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<unknown> {
    const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();

    const startTime = performance.now();

    const functionName = context.getHandler().name;

    console.log(`Function ${functionName} started at ${startTime}`);

    return next.handle().pipe(
      tap(async () => {
        const endTime = performance.now();
        const finalTime = endTime - startTime;

        console.log(`Function ${functionName} finished in ${performance.now() - startTime}ms`);

        console.log(`Request ${req.method} ${req.url} processed in ${finalTime}ms`);
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interceptors **only** trigger on the controller/resolver/gateway. To do something similar for service methods you'd need to use a decorator that modifies and times the function. [Ogma has this built in](https://ogma.jaymcdoniel.dev/en/nestjs/service/#log-and-logall-decorators)